# R: How to search for XML Node

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML file containing individuals' names and currently employed firms, modeled as below:

```
 <Indvl>
      <Info lastNm="Smith" firstNm="John" midNm="Patrick"/>
      <CrntEmps>
        <CrntEmp orgNm="ABC Incorporated" str1="1000 Main Street" city="Helena" state="MT" cntry="UNITED STATES" >
        </CrntEmp>
      </CrntEmps>
</Indvl/>
 <Indvl>
      <Info lastNm="Wesley" firstNm="Jackie" midNm="Jonas"/>
      <CrntEmps>
        <CrntEmp orgNm="XYZ Incorporated" str1="1000 Main Street" city="Helena" state="MT" cntry="UNITED STATES" >
        </CrntEmp>
        <CrntEmp orgNm="Sub Contractor1" str1="1000 Some Street" city="Lincoln" state="NB" cntry="UNITED STATES" >
        </CrntEmp>
      </CrntEmps>
</Indvl/>
```

I am interested in extracting the individual's name information in one table and I am able to accomplish that.

I am also interested in extracting their first shown employer (as in the CrntEmp tag). Most cases have only one but some cases have two. But I want to extract only their first employer:

For John Patrick Smith: ABC Incorporated
For Jackie Jonas Wesley: XYZ Incorporated

Any thoughts on how this can be easily accomplished in R? Your inputs are much appreciated--thank you.

Comment: Please make your data self contained (there is no root node) and show the code you have used ensuring that it works on the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If it's XML, it would be easiest to use the XML library. The only catch with your sample data is that there is no root node. There should be a root to properly parse your data. Here i'll add one called "root"

```
sxml<-'<root><Indvl>
      <Info lastNm="Smith" firstNm="John" midNm="Patrick"/>
      <CrntEmps>
        <CrntEmp orgNm="ABC Incorporated" str1="1000 Main Street" city="Helena" state="MT" cntry="UNITED STATES" >
        </CrntEmp>
      </CrntEmps>
</Indvl>
 <Indvl>
      <Info lastNm="Wesley" firstNm="Jackie" midNm="Jonas"/>
      <CrntEmps>
        <CrntEmp orgNm="XYZ Incorporated" str1="1000 Main Street" city="Helena" state="MT" cntry="UNITED STATES" >
        </CrntEmp>
        <CrntEmp orgNm="Sub Contractor1" str1="1000 Some Street" city="Lincoln" state="NB" cntry="UNITED STATES" >
        </CrntEmp>
      </CrntEmps>
</Indvl></root>'
```

Now we can load and parse this data with

```
library(XML)
doc<-xmlParse(sxml, asText=TRUE)
```

Now what we have an XML object. We can loop through the individuals (the `<Indvl>` nodes) and pull out the Info and the first CrntEmp nodes.

```
xpathApply(doc,"/root/Indvl", function(x) { 
    list(
        indivInfo = xpathSApply(x,"Info/@*"),
        empInfo = xpathSApply(x,"CrntEmps/CrntEmp[1]/@*")
    )   
})
```

We use standard xpath expressions here to find the data we want. Here I return a list for each individual which looks like

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$indivInfo
   lastNm   firstNm     midNm 
  "Smith"    "John" "Patrick" 

[[1]]$empInfo
             orgNm               str1               city              state 
"ABC Incorporated" "1000 Main Street"           "Helena"               "MT" 
             cntry 
   "UNITED STATES" 


[[2]]
[[2]]$indivInfo
  lastNm  firstNm    midNm 
"Wesley" "Jackie"  "Jonas" 

[[2]]$empInfo
             orgNm               str1               city              state 
"XYZ Incorporated" "1000 Main Street"           "Helena"               "MT" 
             cntry 
   "UNITED STATES"
```

so you can easily access that data in an R-friendly list form rather than XML.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have been using the XML package so assuming `doc` is the parsed text:

```
xp <- c("//Info", "//CrntEmps/CrntEmp[1]")
L <- lapply(xp, xpathSApply, doc = doc, fun = xmlAttrs) # list
t(do.call(rbind, L)) # reform into a matrix

##     lastNm   firstNm  midNm     orgNm              str1               city     state cntry          
## [1,] "Smith"  "John"   "Patrick" "ABC Incorporated" "1000 Main Street" "Helena" "MT"  "UNITED STATES"
## [2,] "Wesley" "Jackie" "Jonas"   "XYZ Incorporated" "1000 Main Street" "Helena" "MT"  "UNITED STATES"
```